# How to add padding inbetween items in a WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a horizontal ListView which I would like to ensure that there is some padding between the items (in my case I have Grid inside of the item template), but I don't want there to be any extra padding for the last grid

I want there to be padding where the red line is.

[image]

**EDIT**

H.B.'s suggestion was really helpful, here is the style that I added to get a 5px margin between grids...

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a `Padding` in the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) of the `ListView`. You can use a `DataTrigger` on `RelativeSource PreviousData` being `null` to make it conditional.

Alternatively you could create a new `Panel` which has a concept of spacing.